# why does not open bootstrap modal dialog in the second time?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, bootstrap-modal

I have used a bootstrap modal dialog that is opened by clicking button.
 When I click on button at the first time,modal is opened; by the second clicking, modal dialog does not show and this error is shown in firebug consol:

```
TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function
$(".bs-modal-dialog").modal();
```

how can i solve that? thanks...

these are my code:

```
<div class="modal fade bs-modal-dialog" id="modalDialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
 aria-labelledby ="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">

                 <button class="close" aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">×</button>
                  <h4 id="mySmallModalLabel" class="modal-title"></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>

function EditCompany(CoId) { 


    var link="@Url.Action("EditCompany", "Companies", new { area = "AdminsArea", CoId = "-1"})";

        link=link.replace("-1",CoId);
        $(".bs-modal-dialog").modal('show');
        $(".modal-body").load(link);
        $(".modal-content > .modal-header> #mySmallModalLabel").text("Edit Company");

}
```

```
                    <input type="button" name="EditCompany" value="Edit"  onclick="EditCompany(@co.CompanyID)" class="btn btn-success"/>
```

Comment: Have you included the supporting js which have the `bs-modal-dialog`?

Comment: just a note: don't use inline js code in `onClick` attribute. Bind an event in your js code.

Comment: @Java_User yes i have added bootstrap.min.js, but bs-modal-dialog is my custom class name.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need any JavaScript to do that, Bootstrap already comes with html [attribute for that](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

All you have to do this include `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"` and it should trigger your modal.

[bootply here](http://www.bootply.com/SnC5HHOKqm)